# Outputting 1x3 Video Wall at 5760x1080

Tags: video

I'm looking for the simplest way to create a 1x3 landscape video wall. Where the animation plays at 5760×1080 across the three screens.

The orientation is like this:[image]
I've seen PiWall and that might do what I need (although seems to max out at 1920×1080 total resolution) but if there was some sort of HDMI splitter solution that works like this it would be great and could just run off a laptop. But I feel like a lot of them just clone screens as opposed to the video wall effect?

The screens are three consumer LG 55UK6470PLC TVs. I see there is an LG SuperSign software to do with WebOS for creating video walls but can't get hold of anyone in LG to confirm or deny that it would work with our screens. And I can't find it to download anywhere.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which kind of animation you want to run, the "simplest" solution would be to build a Linux or Windows PC with 3 graphics cards and hook these up though 3 HDMI cables and then anything that runs on that PC can be shown on the 5760x1080 video wall...

As the TVs are 4K-ready, the above solution would also work for a 11520×2160 video wall.

If you need something small (a laptop would be too small), you can go for the [MicroATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX) form factor with 2 Graphics cards for 2 screens and the on-board Intel graphics for the 3rd, but depending on the kind of animation that *could* limit you to maximum 5760x1080.

Comment: You can run more than one display from a card. Something like an Nvidia Quadro K1200 and three mDP -> HDMI adapters + HDMI cables should have no issue running 3 4K 60Hz screens. Just make sure the mDP -> HDMI adapter support 4K 60Hz (I think it’s HDMI 2.0, but I’m not positive)

Comment: @NoahL As the OP was mentioning "simple", "HDMI splitter", "laptop" and "PiWall", I'm assuming as cheap as possible into "simple"...  Second-hand nVidia and MicroATX and Linux should suffice.  If he has more money a new small-form factor Windows 10 PC with a second-hand Nvidia Quadro K1200 should work as well.  **:-)**